# How can I rip a DVD but merge/join episodes

Tags: windows, video, conversion, dvd, ripping

Some background.

I have the Pink Panther Collection, they have about 30 episodes on each DVD.

Now I want to watch this on my `$MobileDevice`. So I went and converted it to both m4v and avi. This of course went splendid with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) and [AutoGK](http://www.autogk.me.uk/) but the problem is that I want **ONE** file per DVD, both Handbrake and AutoGK creates one file per episode.

So here *finally* is my question.

> Does anyone know how to persuade Handbrake or AutoGK to create **one** video file with all the episodes? Or can anyone recommend another (free/cheep) tool for the job?

Oh and no cheating by telling me to join the files after conversion. I have never found a video joiner that did not disappoint me (usually bad audio sync).

Comment: As far as I remember, this was possible with clonedvd by slysoft (whole dvd / single track)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [VOB Blanker](http://jsoto.posunplugged.com/vobblanker.htm), and it's completely free. You can select which chapters (episodes) to be joined and export them all as one huge VOB file that you can then encode using your favorite encoding software.

Hope this helps !

By the way, regarding audio sync issues, avoid using VBRs, and go for CBRs. That solves audio sync issues *most* of the times.

Comment: Any similar tools for mac?

Comment: @Jesper - I honestly have no idea since I'm not using a mac, but I imagine there should be an equivalent.